# why is protobuf-net deserialized object not 'lean'

Tags: c#, json, protobuf-net

We are using the `protobuf-net` library in order to decode MQTT messages provided from the `Inductive Automation - Ignition` software, which is based on `sparkplug_b.proto` payload.

We have generated c# code with the great online protogen tool. 
So now we are able to decode the binarires message objects, to human readable JSON for example :-)
But the deserialized Object contains ('useless'?) objects, which overload the object instance.

Why is the object not "filtered" to provide a 'lean' object instance?

For example:

```
{
  "Body": null,
  "Metrics": [
    {
      "Alias": 0,
      "BooleanValue": false,
      "BytesValue": null,
      "DatasetValue": null,
      "Datatype": 4,
      "DoubleValue": 0,
      "ExtensionValue": null,
      "FloatValue": 0,
      "IntValue": 0,
      "IsHistorical": false,
      "IsNull": false,
      "IsTransient": false,
      "LongValue": 0,
      "Metadata": null,
      "Name": "bdSeq",
      "Properties": null,
      "StringValue": "",
      "TemplateValue": null,
      "Timestamp": 1538568112852
    }
  ],
  "Seq": 18446744073709551615,
  "Timestamp": 1538568112852,
  "Uuid": ""
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an [mcve] showing the data being parsed and the resulting object with the problem you describe?

Comment: I can give you the c# Payload code (which has been generated by protogen online tool) and c# serialize /deserialize code by "copy/past" if this is a good maner to provide it.

Comment: What are the "useless" obejcts in the example? I'm unclear exactly what you mean (I'm the lib author,so I should be able to help)

Comment: In our example the payload object instance is composed of an array of  "Metrics" which is "one of" the data type (information is given by DataType [4, in this example] which is int64 in documentation [https://s3.amazonaws.com/cirrus-link-com/Sparkplug+Topic+Namespace+and+State+ManagementV2.1+Apendix++Payload+B+format.pdf] so the usefull data seems to be ""LongValue": 0," the other <someting>Value are useless in this case.

Comment: We have done some Sparkplug clients, see this NODE-RED client https://github.com/gambitcomminc/node-red-sparkplug and this Python client https://github.com/gambitcomminc/sparkplug-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the Metric definition has a `oneof` field:

```
message Metric {

    // ...

    oneof value {
        uint32   int_value                      = 10;
        uint64   long_value                     = 11;
        float    float_value                    = 12;
        double   double_value                   = 13;
        bool     boolean_value                  = 14;
        string   string_value                   = 15;
        bytes    bytes_value                    = 16;       // Bytes, File
        DataSet  dataset_value                  = 17;
        Template template_value                 = 18;
        MetricValueExtension extension_value    = 19;
    }

    message MetricValueExtension {
        extensions  1 to max;
    }
}
```

And for each of those members, a property is generated in the C# class. But also, for each property, an accompanying `ShouldSerialize` property should be generated by protogen:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeIntValue() => __pbn__itemValue.Is(10);
```

And JSON.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) should respect this property, so it should only serialize the member that the `oneof` field referred to, because all other `ShouldSerialize` properties will return `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. The trouble was linked to the Json serializer and not to the protobuf-net Library.

Comment: @jean.noel IIRC there are ways to configure JSON.NET to use "conditional serialization", which is what the `ShouldSerialize*()` pattern is called